# Efficiently combining values of two lists in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists as follows:

```
list_1 = [set(['Amazon', 'Oracle']), set(['SAP'])]

list_2 = [['Amazon', 388], ['Oracle', 35], ['SAP', 82]]
```

I am trying to combine these lists to produce the following output.

```
comb_list = [[388, 35], [82]]
```

Basically, I want to replace the company names with their respective numbers (they are the stock prices). I tried to loop one of the list inside another, but it is not so efficient and my data set is pretty huge. Is there any way to do this efficiently in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: You want dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = dict(list_2)
print [[d.get(item, None) for item in setItem] for setItem in list_1]
```

**Output**

```
[[35, 388], [82]]
```

Remember, `set` doesn't maintain order. Thats why the output is `[35, 388]` instead of, expected `[388, 35]`.

Comment: Thank you...I never knew about dict type...seems to be the best way to go...and in this case, the order doesn't actually matter...Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, simpler option that doesn't use dictionaries and preserves the original order of the elements:

```
[[v for k, v in list_2 if k in x] for x in list_1]
=> [[388, 35], [82]]
```

One might argue that the above solution is more "Pythonic", but that's subjective and open to discussion.